# Change Apache2 Document Root

Tags: configuration, apache2, ubuntu-14.04

Apache2 on Ubuntu 14.04, fresh installation.

Want to change document root from default `/var/www/html` to `/home/me/mywebroot`

Changed in files `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` as well as in `/etc/apache2/sites-availabe/000-default.conf` and in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` every occurence of `/var/www/html` to `/home/me/mywebroot`.

Now, I do `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`.

Still, when I enter `http://localhost` in the browser, I get the default page located in `/var/www/html` -even though there is no occurence of this folder in any of the config documents.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

first of all, there should not be VirtualHost and not DocumentRoot definition in apache2.conf - did you maybe change the following in apache2.conf?

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

if so, then reverse this change!

second of all, all files in sites-enabled should be symlinks to files in sites-available. so if you first changed one of both and still had to change the other, I would recommend to remove and purge apache2 (make sure /etc/apache2/ is empty after that) and reinstall apache2.

All you should have to do is change DocumentRoot in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default to /home/me/mywebroot and make sure you add a DirectoryIndex directive to reflect whatever Document (eg index.html) you want to serve.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.  What exactly do you mean by "add a DirectoryIndex directive to reflect whatever Document (eg index.html) you want to serve."?

Comment: if you browse to www.mydomain.com you are actually opening the root directory of you vhost - the webserver needs to know which document it should serve to the client without the client specifying www.mydomain.com/index.html. see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex